# How am I taxed as director of limited company that is also employed by another company?

Tags: united-kingdom, accounting, limited-liability-company

I am a UK resident working at a consulting firm earning 33k salary before tax. I have setup a limited company with a friend in which I am a director with 1/3 share in the company. We will soon be launching our flagship product and hope to be receiving an income from this business, which I expect to be 30k+ for the company as a whole over the first year. But our targets have this figure as be close to 80k+.

What are the accounting and tax implications for someone in my situation? I am aware that I will have to submit a Tax return every quarter for the limited company, that will have to be signed off by an accountant (although we may use a service such as Sage to do this). But, as I'm also employed full time I suspect that I could be taxed more than I should as I will have 2 incomes.

Thank you in advance for any advice or information. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What kind of income are you expecting from the second business (for the foreseeable future)? A few thousand here and there or a more substantial amount?

Comment: @marktristan I think close to 30k for the first year. Our target is to have this figure as 80k+. I've updated my post - thanks for your comment.

Comment: How are you taking this are you a salaried employee of this second business?

Comment: I'm not a salaried employee. I'm considering taking this out with dividends, but I am looking into the benefits of other options. e.g paying into an ISA

Answer (score 2):

In this case you have some options.

Not paying your self a salary means you can take money out of the company as a dividend. You will need to pay tax on this BUT you won't need to pay national insurance and the employers National Insurance (an additional 10%). It maybe that your friend needs a salary and you don't. If neither of you need a salary then you can just payout dividends. You don't need to pay out all of the profits as a dividend immediately.

Given your target turnover (80K) you will need to be VAT registered.

Don't forget you will need to fill in a self assesment income tax return and declare any income from the company (either as salary or dividend). It is likely that HMRC will notice that you're a company director and send you a self assesment form.

Finally if you take out money from the company, you will also need to pay tax on account for the following year on the basis of income in this year, this means you need to budget for this i.e. in Jan 2021 you'll need to pay the tax due on dividends for April 2019-April 2020 AND pay half on account (this is on the same basis that you will get a similar dividend the following year) for April 2020-April 2021 (the remainder is due sometime in July)

In short get an accountant to help with the book keeping and personal tax.

BTW it is normal for contractors in the UK to pay themselves a small(ish) salary from the company (usually somewhere between £10K-20K) so they pay some tax and NI but take all the other money as as dividends to avoid paying employers NI.

Comment: The VAT registration thresholds are specified on the HMRC website (https://www.gov.uk/vat-registration-thresholds). It seems that registration would only be required if turnover reaches £85,000. https://www.gov.uk/vat-registration/when-to-register has more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the VAT link. I also should have mentioned that company will have to pay corporation tax https://www.gov.uk/corporation-tax-rates and the new "Making Tax Digital" HMRC campaign means you'll need something like sage from the start.

Comment: @PeterI the rules on dividends have changed recently the OP would need to talk to an accountant

Comment: @Neuromancer I've not been keeping up on that, but after checking it doesn't look like the changes have affected the NI position (which is the big saving) assuming the OP isn't IR35 caught.  I'd still recommend the OP gets an accountant.